# Maximum SOQL offset allowed is 2000 for Paginataion

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to do Pagination but when i click on Last button it gives me error Maximum SOQL offset allowed is 2000.
VF page

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!End}" title="End" value=">>" disabled="{!disableNext}" reRender="panelid,myButtons"/>
```

Apex Code

```
    public PageReference TakeOther()
    {

          if(Selected=='Attachment')
          {
              renderName1=true; 
              renderName2=false;
              renderName3=false;
              renderName4=false;
              String type=selected;
              wrapList.clear();
              shwotable=False;
              List<aggregateResult> aggResults=[SELECT MAX(BodyLength)myMax FROM Attachment];
            System.debug('Max is: ' + aggResults[0].get('myMax'));
            for(aggregateResult a:aggResults)
            {
                sSliderFieldMax=Integer.valueof(a.get('myMax')); 
            }
            System.debug('---------Value of sSliderFieldMax-----::'+sSliderFieldMax);
              sortExpression ='Name';
               string sortFullExp = sortExpression + ' ' + sortDirection;
               String queryList = 'select Id, Name,BodyLength ,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from Attachment where BodyLength  >=' + sSliderFieldMin * 1024 + ' AND BodyLength <=' + sSliderFieldMax * 1024;        
            if (attachmentToUser.OwnerId != NULL) {
                queryList += ' AND OwnerId =\'' + attachmentToUser.OwnerId + '\'';
            }

            system.debug('****Offset Value****'+counter);
            system.debug('****Limit****'+list_size );
            queryList += ' order by ' + sortFullExp + ' Limit ' + list_size + ' offset ' + counter;
             setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryList));
              List<Attachment> attachlist=new List<Attachment>();
             attachlist= Database.query(queryList);
             system.debug('****Offset Value****'+counter);
             i=0;
             for(Attachment a:attachlist)
             {
                 String Owner=a.owner.Name;
                // public wrapRadio(String type,Id id,Integer i,DateTime d,String Name,String OwnerName,Integer size)
                 wrapRadio w=new wrapRadio(type,a.id,i,a.CreatedDate,a.Name,Owner,a.BodyLength);

                 wraplist.add(w);

             } 
         }  

 public PageReference End() { //user clicked end
         counter = total_size - math.mod(total_size, list_size);
        Takeother();
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a known limit imposed by salesforce. 
I think it justifies the behaviour. If we consider a page size of 50 records, there is a very little chance that someone will click next 40 times to get to the end. Usually user will try to narrow the search results.

However if you have large number of records you can use StandardSetController to paginate.

There is a developerforce article with various pros and cons of different techniques available for pagination in salesforce. Here is the Link for that:

[Paginating Data for Force.com Applications](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Paginating_Data_for_Force.com_Applications)

The approaches that are listed are:

- Using Offset as you are doing right now.
- Using Rest API (not listed). It gives you a querylocator using which you can go back and forth.
- Using Standardsetcontroller.