# Paginate 10000+ records

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagination

I want to Paginate 10000+ records. I have already paginate using  offset but it is giving me error of **MAX SOQL OFFSET IS ALLOWED IS 2000**

**Apex Pages**

```
  private ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;//Assignment
//The following code is in Constructor
         this.setCon= new ApexPages.StandardSetController( [select Id, Name,BodyLength,CreatedDate,Owner.Name from Attachment]);
                this.setCon.setpageNumber(1);
                this.setCon.setPageSize(10);
```

Comment: Please read [Pagination Techniques in Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Paginating_Data_for_Force.com_Applications) and [Maximum SOQL offset allowed is 2000 for Pagination](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93128/maximum-soql-offset-allowed-is-2000-for-paginataion/93132#93132). You can try Standard set Controller pagination

Comment: With more than 10k records you will probably need to paginate on the front end. I have used angular to accomplish this in the past.

Comment: @AdrianLarson : Can you send me code for that

Comment: I think the thing to ask here is why do you need to paginate so much data? Is a user every going to conceivably look through that much data without filtering further?

Comment: @LaceySnr There are some filters, but what about if User doesn't use that Filters i.e I need Pagination too

Comment: Personally I'd just limit it to the first few hundred, and display a message to say they've returned a large data set and should consider filtering further. It sounds like denying the user functionality, but really it helps make their life easier.